# Convert an XBAP to a stand alone WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xbap

I have an XBAP that I need to convert to a stand alone WPF application. I have browsed the code and I can't seem to find what makes the application an XBAP as opposed to a standard WPF. Can anyone tell me how I can go back and convert from XBAP to stand alone WPF?

Thank!

Comment: Sounds like it was a "WPF Browser Application" rather than a "WPF Application".  Easiest way is to simply create a new "WPF Application" and copy/link the files, or you can take a look at the resulting XML structure of the two .csproj files and manually change any elements/tags/attributes as needed.  EDIT: Perhaps this will be a stumbling block if you do: http://zainco.blogspot.ca/2009/01/converting-xbap-to-wpf-application.html

Comment: Here's another blog commenting on the changes/process needed: http://davidsandor.com/post/2009/07/17/Convert-a-WPF-Browser-Application-project-to-a-WPF-Application.aspx

Comment: Awesome input, but this is a very large application. I have many csproj files. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Another great resource. But in VS2010 is says I cannot open the csproj file at this time? the app in not running...

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Thanks so much. I wish I could ++ you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it was a "WPF Browser Application" rather than a "WPF Application".

Easiest way is to simply create a new "WPF Application" and copy/link the files, or you can take a look at the resulting XML structure of the two .csproj files and manually change any elements/tags/attributes as needed.

Perhaps this will be a stumbling block if you do: http://zainco.blogspot.ca/2009/01/converting-xbap-to-wpf-application.html

In addition, here's another resource documenting the process: http://davidsandor.com/post/2009/07/17/Convert-a-WPF-Browser-Application-project-to-a-WPF-Application.aspx